getLastRow() - The coordinates of the range are outside the dimensions of the sheet
I have created a series of Google Sheets documents to manage a small organization's inventory, sales, clients, orders, etc. I've employed a series of AppsScript's scripts to automate certain tasks, mostly related to filling the logs or retrieving information. In my opinion, these are simple scripts, nothing fancy. Everything has been working smoothly since then.
Some days ago, one of the scripts started throwing out the error "The coordinates of the range are outside the dimensions of the sheet" when attempting to execute an instance of the function "getLastRow()". If I code my way around the function, then other instances of the "getLastRow()" function start throwing out the error, even if they were working just before and nothing in the code was changed.
Now, without changing anything, the other documents, one by one, started presenting the same issue. Right now, any attempt of using the "getLastRow()" function results in "The coordinates of the range are outside the dimensions of the sheet". Bear in mind that these are simple scripts, some of them just straight up start by calling the last row to get info, then the error is thrown. So, I'm fairly sure that the code is not the problem.
Is there any chance that my files got corrupted? Is there any way to know this? If so, what are the options?
I have coded my way around the "getLastRow()" function, or even feeded directly the row number, then a random instance of the function in the script throws out the error. This keeps happening until all no getLastRow is left.

Can you show a sample of your AppScript? And which lines inside the script that throws the error?

If you are using array formulas in your sheet that can cause problems with the getLastRow() method

Copy of getLastRow() - The coordinates of the range are outside the dimensions of the sheet. See Be Forthright When Cross Posting To Other Sites.
